# Is this code fully recursive? If not, how do I make it so?

Tags: c++

Problem

Consider a currency system in which there are notes of six denominations, namely, Rs. 1, Rs. 2, Rs. 5, Rs. 10, Rs. 50, Rs. 100.
If the sum of Rs. N is input, write a program to compute the smallest number of notes that will combine to give Rs. N.

Input

The first line contains an integer T, the total number of test cases. Then follow T lines, each line contains an integer N.

Output

For each test case, display the smallest number of notes that will combine to give N, in a new line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int count = 0;
        while(n>0){
            if(n>=100){
                count = count + n/100;
                n = n %100;
            }
            else if(n>=50){
                count = count + n/50;
                n = n%50;
            }
            else if(n>=10){
                count = count + n/10;
                n = n%10;
            }
            else if(n>=5){
                count = count + n/5;
                n = n%5;
            }
            else if(n>=2){
                count = count + n/2;
                n = n%2;
            }
            else if(n>=1){
                count = count + n/1;
                n = n%1;
            }
        
        }
        cout<<count<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no recursion at all in this code. You might want to clarify your question.

Comment: No, this code is not recursive. There's also no good reason for it to be so.

Comment: Recursion is when a function calls itself. Either directly (e.g. the function `a` call `a()`) or indirectly (e.g. the function `a` calls `b()`, and the function `b` call `a()`).

Comment: On another note, and a pet peeve of mine, your "assignment" reads very much like it's from a so-called "competition" or "online judge" site, or similar. You have to remember that such sites are *not* any kind of teaching or learning resources, and using them as such could actually hamper your learning process. Once you're knowledgeable in computer science and know a few languages, use such sites for simple brain-teasers, but not for anything serious.

Comment: This is a good reference with regards to dynamic programming. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk

Comment: if your code is correct and produces desired output why bother about recursion? If not, adding recursion alone will also not make it better

Comment: I don't see recursion anywhere in the problem statement.

Comment: Try reading this first : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/recursion/ 
And I so agree with @Someprogrammerdude competitive coding sites are more likely to teach you some very bad habits. Learn C++ first before solving any "problems" there. (And any recursive problem can be solved iteratively and not eat up so much stack space)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out you don't do any recursion, you don't do any function calls at all.

There is also a code smell.

If you remove all the `else` the `while` loop becomes obsolete.

```
        if(n>=100){
            count = count + n/100;
            n = n %100;
        }
        if(n>=50){
            count = count + n/50;
            n = n%50;
        }
        if(n>=10){
            count = count + n/10;
            n = n%10;
        }
        if(n>=5){
            count = count + n/5;
            n = n%5;
        }
        if(n>=2){
            count = count + n/2;
            n = n%2;
        }
        if(n>=1){
            count = count + n/1;
            n = n%1;
        }
```

And you can remove all the `if` as well to get the same result without branching. Which might actually be faster:

```
            count = count + n/100;
            n = n %100;
            count = count + n/50;
            n = n%50;
            count = count + n/10;
            n = n%10;
            count = count + n/5;
            n = n%5;
            count = count + n/2;
            n = n%2;
            count = count + n/1;
            n = n%1;
```

The code is very repetitive. If you put the currency nominations in an array this can be written neater:

```
// outside of main
constexpr std::array coins = {100, 50, 10, 5, 2, 1};

// count coins
int count = 0;
for (const auto & coin : coins) {
    count += n / coin;
    n %= coin;
}
```

Now isn't that much better?

Answer (score 2):

There's no recursion in this code. Recursion is where a function calls itself (directly of indirectly).

It's actually illegal for main to call itself, so to make this code recursive you are going to have to add at least one function. Where you see a loop that's where you should think recursion. So see the while loop, turn that into a function (don't worry about recursion yet). Then when you have that working see if you can replace the while loop part, instead of looping the function just calls itself (recursively).